# Does "pipenv install requests" work with python 3.9.2?

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, python-3.9, pipenv-install

I am following a guide to get NLTK working on my computer and part of the process is setting up a virtual environment so I can manage packages across projects.

Here is the guide I'm following: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

I run into an issue when I reach the part where I'm supposed to "pipenv install requests". I get the message `Installing...Failed to load paths: No Python at 'c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\**python38**\python.exe'`

I have python 3.9.2 installed so my path is `c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\**python39**\python.exe`. Therefore, the python38 directory does not exist, nor does the path in my environment variables.

Do I need to install 3.8.8 to be able to follow this guide? If so, can I install 3.8.8 while 3.9.2 is installed as well, or Can I switch between the two versions? should I just uninstall 3.9.2 and work with 3.8.8?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to specify a python version for pipenv, you can do that with: `pipenv --version 3.9`, you can read more about specifying the version here: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#specifying-versions-of-python

Comment: Thank you. This solves my issue. and for the link, that's very helpful too